# Returning pointers in function

Tags: c++, c++11

What is my mistake here? I just got confused to use pointer as a function.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
char *strcpy(char *, const char *); // string copy
int main()
{
    char string1[20] = "Priteh Taral";
    char string2[20];
    char *result;
    result = strcpy(string2, string1);
    cout << *result << " ";
}

char *strcpy(char *ptr2, const char *ptr1)
{
    while(*ptr1 != '\0')
    {
        *ptr2++ = *ptr1++;
    }
    *ptr2 = '\0';
    return &ptr2;
}
```

How do I return a string as a pointer?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `char*` instead of `std::string`?

Comment: Your `strcpy()` function is declared to return `char *` but it returns a `char **`. Why?

Comment: Doesn't the compiler tell you what's wrong when you return a pointer to a pointer in place of returning a pointer to char?..

Comment: Change the `return` statement: `return ptr2;`

Comment: You are also not allowed to write a function in global scope called `strcpy`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, strcpy should look more like this:

```
char *strcpy(char *ptr2, const char *ptr1)
{
    char *base = ptr2;
    while ((*ptr2++ = *ptr1++) != '\0')
        ;
    return base;
}
```

The function is (in the standard) going to return the *original* value of ptr2 (the destination).  Also, it is simpler to copy the '\0' along with everything else in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just return `ptr2`.

`ptr2` is already a pointer. When you tell it to return `&ptr2`, you're asking for `**char`, which is a pointer to the pointer of char. It's not what you want.